# Reading a file without trailing newlines in python?

Tags: python, list, file, file-io

So i've wrtitten this code:

```
CaseList = []
f_Case = open("C:/Users/Luke Roberts/Desktop/Lists/CaseList.txt", "r")
for line in f_Case:
    CaseList.append(line)
print(CaseList)
```

but when i print the list it comes out as:

```
['Case 1\n', 'Case 2\n', 'Case 3\n', 'Case 4\n', 'Case 5']
```

Is there a way to have it be added to the list without the '\n'?
If not, is there a way to remove the '\n' from each string?

Any and all help is appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

By default, lines are always read in from the file along with the trailing newline. Just call `str.rstrip` and get rid of it.

```
for line in f_Case:
    CaseList.append(line.rstrip())
```

Now, `CaseList` should look something like:

```
['Case 1', 'Case 2', 'Case 3', 'Case 4', 'Case 5']
```

---

*Statutory Advice:* You should wrap file I/O within a `with...as` context manager, it's makes for much cleaner code.

```
with open("C:/Users/Luke Roberts/Desktop/Lists/CaseList.txt", "r") as f_Case:
    for line in f_Case:
        CaseList.append(line)
```

This way, you won't have to call `f_Case.close()` (which you don't currently do, but should've), so you've got the added convenience to go with the safety.

Comment: Keep in mind that `line.rstrip()` will remove more than just newlines. You may want to use `line.rstrip('\r\n')` instead.